# 'for a time' / 'for the time being' interchangeable?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Is there any difference between 'for a time' and 'for the time being'? Are they always interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They typically mean different things.

> For a time.

This is an ambiguous phrase. Without clarification, it could mean an hour or a century. (Or any period of time.) We can generally rule out extreme instances of time in context, but not always:

> Let's manage our greenhouse-gas emissions **for a time** and see how that affects global warming.

It can be reasonably assumed that such a period of time would be in the range of many decades.

---

> For the time being.

This is generally used to denote something only in the immediate or near future.

> You're grounded. I'm going to hold onto your phone **for the time being**.

It would be unusual for this to extend past a few days or weeks.

---

Based on context they can be used interchangeably, but they do have different connotations in general.

Also, if I exchange the phrases used in my example sentences, although understandable, they sound slightly unusual:

> Let's manage our greenhouse-gas emissions **for the time being** and see how that affects global warming.
>
> You're grounded. I'm going to hold onto your phone **for a time**.